# Using PHP preg_replace match result in a math operation?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to find a number in a string, add one to it, and replace it. These don't work:

```
$new_version = 
    preg_replace("/str\/(\d+)str/", "str/".("$1"+1)."str", $original);

$new_version = 
    preg_replace("/str\/(\d+)str/", "str/".(intval("$1")+1)."str", $original);
```

Where 'str' is a very identifiable string, each side of the number (and does not contain numbers).

I realise I can do this in more than one line of code quite easily but it seems like this should be possible.

Comment: Please provide an input and output example so we can take it from there. What is expected from your script based on the input you provide to us.

Comment: Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a callback function allows you to cast a match to number and increment, e.g.:

```
preg_replace_callback(
  "/str\/(\d+)str/",
  function($matches) { return "str/" . ((int)$matches[1] + 1) . "str"; }, 
  $original
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solely using `str_replace` you can get the number from the string, add one to it, and the replace the old number with the new one :

```
$str = 'In My Cart : 11 items';
$nb = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
$nb += 1;
$str = str_replace($nb-1, $nb, $str);
echo $str;
```